# urlmanager doesn't route to the desire page

Tags: yii, yii-url-manager

Shop is the module, product is the controller. My links have an additional param called item, which is the name of the product. When i click on the link, it either never generates the desire url or the page just doesn't show.

I've tried several ways.

`'shop/product/view/<id:\d+>/<item:\w+>'=>'<item>',` this gives me shop/product/view/6?item=name

`'<module:(shop)>/<controller:(product)>/<action:(view)>/<id:\d+>/<item:\w+>'=>'<item:\w+>'` this gives me the same as the above

`shop/product/view/id/<id:\d+>/item/<item:\w+>'>=>'shop/<item:\w+>'`, this gives me error page `Unable to resolve the request "shop/name"`.

I've attempted to write my own extending curlmanager but failed. It gives me the same url.shop/product/view/6?item=name

```
class UrlManager extends CUrlManager
{
    public $connectionID = 'db';

    public function createUrl($manager,$route,$params,$ampersand)
    {
     if ($route == 'shop/product/view'){
            $product = Product::model()->findByPk($params['id']);
            $url=$product->product_name;
            return Yii::app()->createUrl(trim($url,'+'),$params,$ampersand);
    }
```

UPDATE:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
                'urlFormat'=>'path',
                'showScriptName'=>false,
                'rules'=>array(
                            'shop/product/view/id/<id:\d+>/item/<item:\w+>'=>'<item>',              
//'category'=>array('site/category', 'caseSensitive'=>false),      

//'shop'=>array('shop/product/view','caseSensitive'=>false),
//'<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<module>/<controller>/<action>',
//'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>',
// '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
// 'reset/<id:\d+>/<item:\w+>'=>array('site/reset/id', 'caseSensitive'=>false),      
                 ),
         ),
```

Answer (score 0):

`shop/<item:\w+>` looks identical to a controller/action so I believe that it gets overwritten by some other rules you have. Can you post all the rules to see them all?

Also try putting this rule in the beginning of the rules array, that should make it have priority over other rules.

Comment: Yes, I have placed it on the top, but the problem is still there. Please see the update. My other thought is, does it matter how the other page writes the link? So the link thatis written as `yii:app()->createUrl('product/view',array('id'=>1,'name'=>$model->name'));` will this effect how it was redirected? I can't think of any other cause.

Comment: I believe it should be yii:app()->createUrl('shop/product/view',array('id'=>1,'name'=>$model->name'));

Comment: Also your rule is wrong I believe. why even use class UrlManager extends CUrlManager

Comment: Just use a rule like 'product/<name:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'shop/product/view', when you declare the route you should use Yii:app()->createUrl('shop/product/view',array('id'=>1,'name'=>$model->name'));

Comment: some debugging for your code shop/product/view/id/<id:\d+>/item/<item:\w+> does not match yii:app()->createUrl('shop/product/view',array('id'=>1,'name'=>$model->name'));, you are using item in 1 place and name in another

Comment: oops sorry, i meant to type item and it is shop/product/view. I can't think of another way so I tried extend curlmanager :/

Comment: this is exactly how i am doing it: url rule
product/'<title:.*?>/<id:\d+>'=>'shop/product',

i create the urls with Yii::app()->createUrl('shop/product',array('id'=>$product->id, 'title'=>$product->name))

your only difference is that you format the URL in a sightly different way and you use a module (I use a module too but I extend the controller in my application). The changes should be minimal. No need for the url manager.